# .NET MAUI equivalent of Xamarin.Android.Support.V7 packages?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maui

So I'm trying to migrate a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI, but I noticed that the Android.Support.V7 namespace isn't available in in the latter, though Xamarin.Forms has the Xamarin.Android.Support.V7 packages available.  Does .NET MAUI have anything similar that I can use?

If you would like to duplicate this yourself, simply add the following line anywhere in a .NET MAUI app:
`private Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;`

Comment: When you say "add the following line anywhere", if this is supported at all [I don't know if it is], it would be in a file inside `Android` folder. Are you trying it there? I haven't tried this; maybe [.NET 6 and Mobile SDKs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/the-new-net-multi-platform-app-ui-maui/#net-6-and-mobile-sdks)'s video link is informative. Bottom line: Platform-specific code is part of the ".Net 6+" API. Maui is a cross-platform UI layer on top of that.

Comment: A side note: It can be inside the Android folder or any other Android-specific location (via filename or foldername based multi-targeting - it doesn't need to be the default Android folder). I also think that using an old support library might not be necessary. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I forgot about AndroidX and I remembered about AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar, I'll try that to make sure things work correctly.  Thanks!